# Problems with use list/filter/lambda/ in loop

Tags: python, sql, list, filter, lambda

`

```
purchase_taxes = frappe.db.sql("""SELECT account_head from `tabPurchase Taxes and Charges` where parent=%s """,('Company1'),as_dict=1)
########################
taxes =[test1, test2, test3]
##########################
for tax in taxes:
    resp= list(filter(lambda item_tax: (item_tax['account_head'] == tax), purchase_taxes))
    if len(resp)>0:
        print('resp')
```

`

I'm trying to get the repeating values ​​of the taxes list by comparing them to the purchase_taxes list.
I do this by going through the taxes list and using list(filter(lambda))) I should get the repeated data.
Instead of the result I get NameError: name 'tax' is not defined and I don't understand why or the solution.

I share the content of the lists...

taxes = 1.1.3.02.001 - VAT TWELVE PURCHASES - LONG

purchase_taxes=[{'account_head': '1.1.3.02.010 - ZERO VAT PURCHASES - LONG'}, {'account_head': '2.1.1.04.009 - VAT WITHHOLDINGS (30) - LONG'}, {'account_head': '2.1.1.04.010 - VAT WITHHOLDINGS (70) - LONG'}, {'account_head': '1.1.3.02.001 - VAT TWELVE PURCHASES - LONG'},
{'account_head': '2.1.1.04.007 - WITHHOLDS AT SOURCE (1) - LONG'}]

I tried to look at the data types that I was using, but they are the correct ones
taxes = <class 'str'>
purchase_taxes=<class 'list'>
resp should be equal to
resp=1.1.3.02.001 - VAT TWELVE PURCHASES - LONG
apparently there is an error in the line resp=list(filter(lambda...))

Answer (score 0):

Following procedure can help I think,

```
# extract the account heads
account_heads = [p_t['account_head'] for p_t in purchase_taxes]

# filtering function
def check_repeated(acc_heads, t):
    occurances = [1 for a_h in acc_heads if a_h == t ]
    return len(occurances) > 1
# filtering 
repeadted_taxes = list(filter(lambda t: check_repeated(account_heads, t), taxes))
```